# Can I use REST::Client to call custom verbs such as "REJECT"?

Tags: perl, rest

I have to make a call to a third-party REST API with a `REJECT` verb.

Attempting to simply use REST::Client::request failed, complaining that REJECT is not one of the few standard methods:

> REST::Client exception: First argument to request must be one of GET, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD

Can I still use REST::Client to make my call? Do I have to use a different library altogether? I know that, as a last resort a `curl` incantation might work, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't know enough about REST to know if this is a sufficiently universal solution to the problem, but a little googling seems to agree this should work for most well-behaved REST APIs, including the one I used:

```
$client->addHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'REJECT');
$client->POST(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

**No, you cannot.**

[REST::Client has the verbs built into an *error check*](https://metacpan.org/source/KKANE/REST-Client-273/lib/REST/Client.pm#L331) that is part of the `request` method and is not injectable, so you cannot simply overwrite it without overwriting and rebuilding the whole `request`.

> ```
> #error check
> croak "REST::Client exception: First argument to request must be one of GET, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD" unless $method =~ /^(get|patch|put|post|delete|options|head)$/i;
> ```

**However**, if that is not a problem, you could sub-class it, overwrite `request` with an exact copy but a different regex, and add your own convenience method for `REJECT`. It would look something like that.

```
package REST::Client::WithReject;
use parent 'REST::Client';

sub request {
    my $self = shift;

   # original code ...

    #error check
    croak "REST::Client exception: First argument to request must be one of GET, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, REJECT" unless $method =~ /^(get|patch|put|post|delete|options|head|reject)$/i;

    # original code ...
}

sub REJECT {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->request('REJECT', @_);
}
```

Then you can use your package instead of the original one. Of course, it will not benefit from updates to REST::Client, so you would have to update yourself if `request` changes in a future release.

This works because the underlying HTTP::Request does not care about the method at all. It uses it verbatim. You can put whatever you want there, be it `Get`, `GET`, `get` or `GETTHEFSCKOUT`. Most likely the server on the other end will not agree with the last one though...